# find the right journal to publish my manuscript

Tags: journals, paper-submission, open-access

I'm about to publish my work in a journal,

I'm searching for those having an impact factor, indexed and non-paying.

I used [Elsevier finder](https://journalfinder.elsevier.com/),  [Springer suggester](https://journalsuggester.springer.com/), DBLP,...tp pick up a list of journals in my research area then, I send it to my supervisor, who shocked me with another criterion which is 'open access', he said that a journal having an open access option is a paying journal and I'm not allowed to publish in it.

Could you please tell me what is this open access option?

how to find the right journal with the criteria that my supervisor and I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article on [open access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access) on Wikipedia for what it is.

You can find open access journals in the [Directory of Open Acces Journals](https://doaj.org/), the [Free Journal Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Journal_Network), and by searching the websites of the publishers who are members of [OASPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Access_Scholarly_Publishers_Association). That said, I'm honestly rather surprised that your supervisor doesn't simply suggest a journal to publish in. Directly asking him would be the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about [open access publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access) in various online places such as the wikipedia article linked here.

Note the section on funding, however. Since readers of open access materials can do so without charge, the costs must be covered by other means. Often this means that the authors are charged a fee for publishing.

Perhaps your advisor is objecting to the cost of publication. But perhaps he is confusing it with predatory journals that also usually charge authors for publishing. The difference is that open access journals are often completely reputable (as are the ones you list), but predatory journals are not.

I believe that some reputable journals will publish either with or without the open access option. You can then avoid the fees (perhaps), but readers will need to subscribe or otherwise pay the publishers for access.

However, even without open access, most university libraries can obtain access to scholarly materials through sharing arrangements, so researchers can get access without fee. And when a journal is published by a scholarly society, the articles may be accessible to members for reduced (or no) fees.

Comment: Just to add, some open-access publishers like Frontiers or Plos offer publication waivers I believe. Otherwise, I would always recommend uploading preprints or accepted manuscripts to repositories (e.g., university repositories, arxiv, academia.edu, researchgate) for people not affiliated with any scholar body to find (depending on whether this is normative for one's field).